# How do I get the specific values in a JSON Output on PowerShell?

Tags: c#, azure, powershell-3.0

```
Get-AzureRmMetric -DetailedOutput -MetricName '\Processor Information(_Total)\% Processor Time'
```

This is the command and I only want the Average values. How do I extract it?

Here is how it looks like on the PS Window.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bez3K.png)

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked by me yesterday, and while I could not find a direct solution via PowerShell, I did make it work through Visual Studio. Here's what I did.

Based on a little bit of tinkering around, I stored the output as a String and then manipulated the string using the '`Regex.Split`' method.